# Insert blank row based on cell value - 1

Tags: excel, vba

I have numbers in col R (sometimes there are 4 lines on a sheet, other times over 1000), and need to add blank rows beneath any row that has more than the value 1 in column R.

Row 2 has value of 1 in column R so no blanks are needed, Row 3 has value of 3, so I need to add 2 blank rows below it. Row 4 has value of 2 so I need to add 1 blank row below, etc.

I found this code on here and it was working but now it is not:

```
`Sub Main()

'---Variables---
Dim source As Worksheet
Dim startRow As Integer
Dim num As Integer
Dim val As String
Dim i As Long

'---Customize---
Set source = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'The sheet with the data
startRow = 2 'The first row containing data

'---Logic---
i = startRow 'i acts as a row counter
Do While i <= source.Range("O" & source.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
'looping until we hit the last row with a value in column E
    num = source.Range("R" & i).Value 'Get number of appearances
    val = source.Range("A" & i).Value 'Get the value
    If num > 1 Then 'Number of appearances > 1
        Do While num > 1 'Create rows
            source.Range("A" & i + 1).EntireRow.Insert 'Insert row
            num = num - 1
            i = i + 1 'Next row
        Loop
    End If
    i = i + 1 'Next row
Loop

End Sub`
```

Comment: Can you please explain specifically how it is not working?

Comment: It isn't working at all. It isn't adding any blanks!

Comment: `Sheets(1)` is not sure that the same as `Sheet1`, so check the name of the sheet where the data are. It is preferably that use the name of the sheet instead of the `Item` value of the collection.

Answer (score 1):

When inserting rows it's easier to work from the bottom to the top.  For example:

```vb
Sub Main()
    
    Dim source As Worksheet, num As Long, c As Range
    
    With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1) 'The sheet with the data
        'start in ColR, at last-occupied row in ColO
        Set c = .Cells(.Cells(.Rows.Count, "O").End(xlUp).Row, "R")
        Debug.Print "Starting at " & c.Address & " on '" & .Name & "'"
    End With
    
    Do While c.Row > 1
        num = c.Value 'Get number of appearances
        If num > 1 Then
            c.Offset(1).Resize(num - 1).EntireRow.Insert shift:=xlShiftDown
        End If
        Set c = c.Offset(-1)
    Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: This is not doing anything either!

Comment: Then something is off about your description.  Do you have data in Col O, as suggested by your posted code? What does `Debug.Print c.Address` give if you add that just before the loop?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you need to change `O` to `R` in the statement:

```
Do While i <= source.Range("O" & source.Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
```

This code determines last row that will be processed in the loop. If there is no data in the column `O` - nothing is processed.

Comment: I have tried that but it still is not running at all

Comment: Try to set a breakpoint into this function in the Visual Basic Editor to make sure that this macro is executed. Possible problem is somewhere else.